# storing binary password hashes with playframework

Tags: java, playframework

How i store a binary hash password in a binary type column with the CRUD module? In pure JAVA Usually i use the Apache Commons codec libs to store the binary hash into a postgresql bytea column, but i cannot generate neither the bytea column with the Model class or the binary hash... Any help please.

In the Model class i set the property as bytea with annotations as follows

```
@Required
@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="BYTEA NOT NULL")
@Password
public byte[] hash;
```

, but the CRUD controller dont display a textbox to put an input for the password to be hashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate `@Transient String` field for the password, to be filled in from CRUD input:

```
@Password
@Transient
public String password;
```

Then remove the `@Required` annotation from your hash field. It does not need to be filled in from CRUD at all.

Next, create a new method and annotate it with `@PrePersist`, so it will be executed before the model is saved:

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() throws Exception {
    this.hash = Codec.hexMD5(this.password.getBytes());
}
```

---

*UPDATE:*

To have the `@Transient` field appear on your CRUD view, you need to customize the `blank` view of CRUD of your controller. Open a shell / command prompt and execute the following command (replacing "your_controller" with the actual name of your controller class):

```
play crud:ov --template your_controller/blank
```

This should copy the CRUD blank.html template to `views/your_controller/blank.html` in your application. Open that file, look for the `#{crud.form /}` tag, and add the following code below it:

```
<div class="crudField crud_password">
    <label for="object_password">&{'label.password'}</label>
    <input id="object_password" type="password" name="object.password" value="" />
    <span class="crudHelp"></span>
</div>
```

The password field should now appear after your other form fields.

Comment: thanks for your response. i was exploring the database way of triggering the hash at the insertion, but i'll definetly gonna try your response.

Comment: the @Transient field does not show in the Users CRUD form. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: No, you're right, I forgot that the @Transient field does not appear in the view automatically. I updated my answer with added instructions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, the data now is being stored, but i cannot retrieve the data now. I'm trying to modify the show.html template like i did with the blank.html one, but i guess i can set the question as answered.