# special update with CRUD module

Tags: playframework

I come from the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9372684/574460.
I managed to store binary data on the database with the code on the link i put early. I'll put it again for a quicker reference:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="BYTEA NOT NULL", nullable=false) @Password
public byte[] password;

@Required @Password @Transient
public String hash;

@ManyToOne
@Required
public Departamento departamento;

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void hashPassword() throws Exception {
    this.password = Crypto.passwordHash(this.hash, Crypto.HashType.SHA512).getBytes();
    System.out.println(this.password);
}
```

The problem now is i cannot update the password. I changed the show template to get the data as in the blank template but i simply cannot update the data.
The add of the @PreUpdate annotation do not seems to work the way it should.

What can i do? Any advice will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

As @grahamrb sugested, it seems i only need to override the set method to save and update the data. Thanks  @grahamrb

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the "hash" object and instead override the _public void setPassword()_ method and have your hashing algorithm in there?

Comment: How i should do it `code`public void setHash(String hash) {
        this.hash = Crypto.passwordHash(hash).getBytes();
    }`code` will suffice? Should i do a getter too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that method which related with `@PreUpdate` annotation called only if some object field value was changed. But when you try to update `@Transient` field it is impossible to detect changes and method is not invoking.

I encountered with similar problem and the best solution I could find - store in a database field with a surrogate value for tell to Hibernate about changes. For example:

**Model context:**

```
public Long updatingHackHash;

public void renewUpdatingHackHash() {
    this.updatingHackHash = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

**Controller context:**

```
public static void save(MyModel myModel) {

    // ...

    myModel.renewUpdatingHackHash();
    myModel.save();

    // ...
}
```